# persisting IntelliJ IDEA "Kotlin | Style issues" settings in .editorconfig file

Tags: intellij-idea, editorconfig

how can I persist Kotlin inspection settings in file .editorconfig in IteliiJ IDEA  so that I could share them with a team through git?

Exact settings name is:

```
Editor > Inspections > Kotlin > Style issues > Accessor call that can be replaced with property access syntax
```

I'd like to change it's Severity level.

I tried to follow

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Code_Analysis__Code_Inspections.html#list-of-configurable-code-inspections

and

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html#editorconfig

but with no luck.

How exactly should .editorconfig entry look like for that settings and where can I find full list of property keys?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspections have nothing common with `.editorconfig` files.

### Editorconfig

Editorconfig is about Code Style (**Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Kotlin**)
All the styles could be exported via this button: [image]

There are too many options to describe them all. That is why export is easier.
General options could be found at https://editorconfig-specification.readthedocs.io/#supported-pairs

### Kotlin inspections

Inspections are IDE-specific. And they can be exported/imported to an XML file via this button:
[image]

But there is no possibility to export an individual inspection. Instead, you can create a project-wide inspections profile with your team and use it across.

You can share the inspection profile along with the project. Just add this file to your project's VCS: `.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml`

Comment: yep, I'm aware of Project_Default.xml file, however it looks like IDEA reads it only on startup (doesn't refresh settings on git pull nor on branch change).

Regarding "Inspections have nothing common with .editorconfig files" - well for C# they are configurable in .editorconfig so they could potentially be configurable for Kotlin (please check first link)